# TJsonTextWriter with nesting

Tags: json, delphi

Please help me to generate JSON format like these lines using Delphi:

```json
[{
    "trans_num" : "00001",
    "cust_name" : "Sample Customer Name",
    "remarks" : "",
    "details":
    [
        {
        "itemcode" : "ITM0001",
        "quantity" : 1
        },

        {
        "itemcode" : "ITM0002",
        "quantity" : 1
        }
    ]
}]
```

Here's my unfinished code:

```pascal
uses System.JSON, System.JSON.Types, JSON.Writers;

procedure TFrm_Main.cmdReaderClick(Sender: TObject);
var
    Writer: TJsonTextWriter;
    StringWriter: TStringWriter;
begin
    StringWriter := TStringWriter.Create();
    Writer := TJsonTextWriter.Create(StringWriter);
    Writer.Formatting := TJsonFormatting.Indented;

      Writer.WriteStartArray;
        Writer.WriteStartObject;
            Writer.WritePropertyName('trans_num');
            Writer.WriteValue('0001');
            Writer.WritePropertyName('cust_name');
            Writer.WriteValue('Sample Customer Name');
            Writer.WritePropertyName('remarks');
            Writer.WriteValue('Confirmed');

        Writer.WriteEndObject;
      Writer.WriteEndArray;

    ShowMessage(StringWriter.ToString);
end;
```

Output:

```json
[{
    "trans_num" : "00001",
    "cust_name" : "Sample Customer Name",
    "remarks" : "Confirmed"
}]
```

Comment: please repost well formatted JSON code, you want to share. For better understanding.

Comment: The output was the same as what you wanted - you have to take better care when posting. Where's the problem tho? Everything's there - just start using `.WriteStartArray()` and the others again instead of wanting to write `"Confirmed"`.